# What does SVN checkout do?

Tags: svn

Does "SVN" checkout put a build.xml file within the folder that is chosen?

Currently, I do not have permissions to the SVN repository. So I thought that I might just skip the SVN checkout step and proceed with the build. But I am getting an error that says Build.xml file does not exist. Is this build.xml file provided once the SVN checkout is performed?

Comment: Wow.. where to begin... build.xml *should* be part of the code.  What are you building if you haven't done the checkout yet?  Svn is just a [Revision Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system.  build.xml is the [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) build file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`svn checkout` checks out (retrieves) a working copy of the repository into the specified folder. If you don't have access to the repository, and there's not already a current copy of the source in the folder, you can't possibly do a build.

If there is a current copy of the source there, it should include `build.xml`.

If you *had* access to the repository, `svn checkout` would only retrieve a copy of `build.xml` if there was one in the repository for the copy being checked out. In other words, it won't magically add a `build.xml` if one doesn't exist in the repository.

Comment: Hope it's not a problem to insert this question here, rather than ask new question.  So I should use Checkout instead of Export to pull down a repository to my disk (even if I only intend on changing a small folder within that structure)?

Comment: @NealWalters: Yes, if you intend to check those changes back in later. (You should read the SVN book (Google it), which is free. It provides a lot of detail and some practical examples for most SVN activities and uses.)

Answer (score 1):

Ant is an XML based configuration tool that is used for build automation (Compiling sources and packaging binaries). 
Build.xml is the major control section that has the information of all the tasks that have to be done automatically in sequence.
Build.bat or sh  + Build properties is just a script file that prepares the system environment before build tasks are executed.

Now this whole thing along with the application sources are maintained in any version control system on a central server(SVN,CVS...)

When a developer wanted to build and package the applcication on his local system .. he should perform an SVN Checkout / SVN Update of the root folder that has sources and build scripts. Usually the latest version will be checkout.